# SQLite JSON1 example for JSON extract\set

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

SQLite has now an experimental JSON1 extension to work with JSON fields. The functions to choose from look promising, but I don't get how to use them in the context of a query.

Suppose I created the following table:

```
sqlite> create table user(name,phone);
sqlite> insert into user values('oz', json_array(['+491765','+498973']));
```

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) shows how to use `json_each` in a query, but all other functions lack some in context documentation.

Can someone with SQLite experience provide a few examples of how to use:

- `json_extract`
- `json_set`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

So, here is a first example of how to use `json_extract`. First, the data is a inserted in a bit different way:

```
insert into user (name, phone) values("oz", json('{"cell":"+491765", "home":"+498973"}'));
```

Now, we can select all the users phone numbers as in normal sql:

```
sqlite> select user.phone from user where user.name=='oz';
{"cell":"+491765","home":"+498973"}
sqlite>
```

But, what if we don't care about land lines and we want only cell phones?
Enter `json_extract`:

```
sqlite> select json_extract(user.phone, '$.cell') from user;
+491765
```

And this is how to use `json_extract`.

Using `json_set` is similar. Given that the we want to update the cell phone:

```
sqlite> select json_set(user.phone, '$.cell', 123) from \
        user;
{"cell":123,"home":"+498973"}
```

You can combine those function calls in other SQL queries. Thus, you can
use SQLite with structured data and with unstructured data in the form of
JSON.

Here is how to update the user cell phone only:

```
sqlite> update user 
   ...> set phone =(select json_set(user.phone, '$.cell', 721) from user)
   ...> where name == 'oz';
sqlite> select * from user;
oz|{"cell":721,"home":"+498973"}
```

Comment: Is there a way you can do a select statement based on a value in the json field?

Comment: something like select json_extract(user.phone, '$.cell = 491765') from user;

Comment: @Oz123 what if I have nested json, is it still possible?

Comment: What if I don't know the name of the key?  Is there some way to get the name of the first key and value of an object?

Comment: @Michael json_each / json_tree ?

Comment: what should be the type for column that accepts json? (for above example, type for phone column) is Text type fine?

Comment: Text type is fine @EricAhn

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica you can write queries like 
`select people.data from people where json_extract(people.data, '$.age') > 29`, where data is a TEXT column with a JSON value containing the age property as an integer.